# How to convert recieved string to enum

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, string, enums

I am receiving some json object from a file, and I want to parse some of the fields to predefined values.

```
import jobsRaw from '../../data/jobs.json';
```

I created a type that describes my object, but I want the ***status*** to have only my predefined values, if else I might define a fallback value.

```
export type Job = {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  status: JobStatus;
  warehouseId: string;
  relatedCell: string;
  relatedDocument: string;
  partnerName: string;
  potatoType: string;
  relatedBoxes: string[];
  boxCount?: number;
  createdAt: string;
  completedAt: string;
};
```

This is the mapping I'm trying with:

```
const jobs: Job[] = jobsRaw.map((job: Job) => ({
  ...job,
  status: JobStatus[job.status],
  boxCount: job.relatedBoxes.length,
}));
```

I want to create some sort of JobStatus type that I can parse my received string value with.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to implement this I would go for a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to check if the data is a proper `JobStatus`. Maybe something like this:

```js
const isJobStatus = (value: any): value is JobStatus =>
  value && Object.values(JobStatus).includes(value);

const jobs: Job[] = jobsRaw.map((job: Job) => ({
  ...job,
  status: isJobStatus(job.status) ? job.status : JobStatus.SOME_DEFAULT_STATUS,
  boxCount: job.relatedBoxes.length,
});
```

With this approach you could even use a different type in map iterator like below to better represent the "raw" data because the type predicate will cast `job.status` as a proper `JobStatus` when it returns true. I've also made `boxCount` mandatory in `Job` and removed it from `JobRaw`, by doing like this you won't need to make it optional.

```js
export type Job = {
  type: string;
  id: string;
  status: JobStatus;
  warehouseId: string;
  relatedCell: string;
  relatedDocument: string;
  partnerName: string;
  potatoType: string;
  relatedBoxes: string[];
  boxCount: number;
  createdAt: string;
  completedAt: string;
};

type JobRaw = Omit<Job, 'status' | 'boxCount'> & { status: string };

const jobs: Job[] = jobsRaw.map((job: JobRaw) => ({
  ...job,
  status: isJobStatus(job.status) ? job.status : JobStatus.SOME_DEFAULT_STATUS,
  boxCount: job.relatedBoxes.length,
}));
```